For which finite groups $G$ do we have some $g\in G$ such that $g^G=(g^{-1})^G$?
The Question:

For which finite groups $G$ do we have some $g\in G$ such that $g^G=(g^{-1})^G$, where $h^G$ is the conjugacy class of $h$ in $G$?

Thoughts:
I think this is the case when (but not exactly when) $|g|=2$, so, by Lagrange's Theorem (and Cauchy's Theorem), it holds for all groups with even order.
I suppose we could use the Class Equation somehow, since $|h^G|=|(h^{-1})^G|$, right?

Such a thing is possible: consider $\Bbb Z_2$.

Look for instance at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group More generally, any quotient of $\langle a,b\mid bab^{-1}=a^{-1}\rangle$, and any group containing such a quotient. That's all.

Groups of even order have the property as you say. Groups of odd order don't. [If $g$ inverts $h$ then $g^2$ centralises $h$; in a group of odd order $g$ is a power of $g^2$ and then $g$ will centralise and not invert $h$.]

If $G=S_n$, then every $g$ is conjugate to its inverse (same holds in dihedral groups). In particular, every finite $G$ can be embedded in a finite $K$ where every element is conjugate to its inverse.

@ancientmathematician Another proof that odd order groups don't is that if a (non-trivial) conjugacy class contains an element and its inverse, it can be split into pairs of inverse elements (the inverse of every element of the class is in the class). Therefore the class has even size, and this can only happen if the group order is even.

An element $g \in G$ which is conjugate to its inverse is said to be real. If $G$ is finite, this is equivalent to the condition that all character values $\chi(g)$ are real (since $\chi(g^{-1}) = \overline{\chi(g)}$). So if you have the character table of $G$ you can find real elements by finding columns of the character table that are real.
A complete classification seems difficult (beyond what Anne Bauval mentions in the comments). A group in which every element is real is called ambivalent. As mentioned in the comments, the symmetric and dihedral groups are famous examples, and there's literature on such groups if you want to look it up.
